# Find a value for "c"

Tags: calculus, limits

> For what value of $c$ is $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x+c}{x-c}\right)^x = e?$$

I am unsure of how to start this question in any sense.

Comment: No, if c was zero it would not equal to "e"

Comment: Hint:  $e=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n$

Answer (score 6):

Here's a hint:

$$e = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x.$$

Let's let $y=x-c$ in your expression (so that $x = y+c$), then since $x\to\infty$, $y\to\infty$ and we get

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x+c}{x-c}\right)^x = \lim_{y\to\infty}\left(\frac{y+c+c}{y}\right)^{y+c} = \lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{2c}{y}\right)^y\left(1+\frac{2c}{y}\right)^c.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So then c could be equal to 1, since it will leave you with a "2/y" instead of "1/x" in the original which is still close?

Comment: Well remember, you **need** $\dfrac{1}{y}$ inside, not $\dfrac{2c}{y}$ to get $e$...

Comment: Oh, so then you would want to make c equal to 1/2 to get that 1/y?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Definitely. I didn't want to overcomplicate things but it's good advice.

Comment: @Bryce That's exactly right.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!!

Comment: @Bryce You're very welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you take logarithm on both sides, you get

$\operatorname{ln}(\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{x+c}{x-c})^x)=\operatorname{ln}(e)$.

What do you know about the function $\operatorname{ln}$?

Comment: ln will equate to 1 when ln(e)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you might not know (or be allowed to use) that fact yet, which is natural.

Comment: WHen you take ln of both sides, the RHS should equate to 1, not 0?

Comment: I corrected it.

Comment: I could well be missing something, but can you even do anything with the left hand side? Is there a way to move the logarithm into the limit? Even if you can, that certainly raises my eyebrow.

Answer (score 1):

You also have a solution using Taylor series.

Let $$A=\left(\frac{x+c}{x-c}\right)^x$$ $$\log(A)=x \log \left(\frac{x+c}{x-c}\right)=x \log \left(\frac{1+\frac cx}{1-\frac cx}\right)$$ For small values of $y$, we also have $$\log \left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)=2 \Big(\frac{y}{1}+\frac{y^3}{3}+\cdots\Big)$$ Replace $y$ by $\frac{c}{x}$ and so $$\log(A)=2x \Big(\frac{ c}{x}+\frac{ c^3}{3 x^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^4\right))=2 c+\frac{2 c^3}{3 x^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^4\right)$$ $$A=e^{2 c}\Big(1+\frac{2 c^3 }{3 x^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^4\right)\Big)$$ which shows the limit and how the expression goes to the limit.